# How to find an element in one of several MongoDBs subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a mongodb collection that contains documents that contain a subdocument with the following form:

```
    'Store': {   'cupboard1': {   'Cheese': 21,
                              'Humous': 25,
                              'Natchos': 10,
                              'Olives': 10,
                              'stockItems': 66},
                  'cupboard2': {  'Cheese': 11,
                              'Humous': 9,
                              'Olives': 2,
                              'Sausage': 3,
                              'stockItems': 25},
                  'whole':  {  'Chris': 32,
                              'Olives': 11,
                              'Sausage': 3,
                              'Humous': 34,
                              'Natchos': 10,
                              'stockItems': 91}
```

I want to build a number of queries that depend upon finding documents based on a name of a food item (using python3/Pymongo).
I can see that I could initially perform a search on the 'whole' subdocument, to get data on documents that match. But, how can I write a query to find details of which cupboards I can find an item in?
Also, is there a more direct way to find the cupboard? ie if I know I want to find sausage but don't know which if any cupboards it might be found in?

Comment: I havent checked, but I assume you can do this using javascript function  with cursor.Inside this function possible you can iterate bson document properties.refer to this page http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That seems like a good lead. I'll take a look. I should have added that I'm using python/pymongo rather than the shell (I'll update the question) - but I think that I should be able to do the same with pymongo on a cursor object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the real issue here is that the current structure of the data does not support what you are trying to do very well. There are better ways to do this that most importantly reduce the load of any initial query in order to find documents that "might" contain the desired item in a given cupboard.

Consider the basic premise of "searching" for a document that might contain a "Sausage" in one of the "cupboards" in the document. You are certainly correct in your observation that in this structure it would be best to search the "whole" to test for presence. But consider the query that does this:

```js
collection.find({ "Store.whole.Sausage": { "$exists": True } })
```

That's not really great. The reason why it's not ideal is because you are testing for the presence of a "key" in the document, and that means that an "index" cannot be used and the whole collection needs to be "scanned" in order to get that basic level of result.

Even once obtained, then determining "which" cupboard(s) contain this item is a matter of code to iterate the object properties and find the match. Over a single document it would generally make sense to do this rather than deferring to the server, but to generally illustrate, there is of course the operation using mapReduce which can run code on the server and return results different from the document presented ( as a shell example ):

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function () {
      var Store = this.Store,
          id = this._id

      Object.keys(Store)
        .filter(function(key) {
          return key != "whole";
        })
        .forEach(function(key) {
          Object.keys( Store[key] )
            .forEach(function(el) {
              if ( el == "Sausage" )
                emit(id, {
                  cupboards: [
                    {
                      cupboard: parseInt(key.match(/\d+$/)[0]),
                      item: el,
                      qty: Store[key][el]
                    }
                  ],
                  totalQty: Store[key][el]
                });
            });
        });
    },
    function (key,values) {

      var result = { cupboards: [], totalQty: 0 };

      values.forEach(function(el) {
        el.cupboards.forEach(function(item) {
          result.cupbards.push(item);
        });
        result.totalQty += el.totalQty;
      });

      return result;

    },
    { 
        "query": { "Store.whole.Sausage": { "$exists": true } },
        "out": { "inline": 1 }
    }
)
```

Which would return something like this:

```js
{
    "results" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5563db1c22cfcc577e5d7450"),
            "value" : {
                "cupboards" : [
                    {
                        "cupboard" : 2,
                        "item" : "Sausage",
                        "qty" : 3
                    }
                ],
                "totalQty" : 3
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The same approach can basically be followed in client code where you inspect the content of the document to find the matches. But as I stated, the real problem here is that initial "query" which is not optimal and is "brute force" check on the collection.

A better case would be to structure your data like this:

```js
{
    "cupboards": [
        { "cupboard": 1, "item": "Cheese", "qty": 21 },
        { "cupboard": 1, "item": "Humous", "qty": 25 },
        { "cupboard": 1, "item": "Nachos", "qty": 10 },
        { "cupboard": 1, "item": "Olives", "qty": 10 },
        { "cupboard": 2, "item": "Cheese", "qty": 11 },
        { "cupboard": 2, "item": "Humous", "qty": 9 },
        { "cupboard": 2, "item": "Olives", "qty": 2 },
        { "cupboard": 2, "item": "Sausage", "qty": 3 }
    ]
}
```

Now "item" is a "data point" which can be indexed in order to get just those documents matching the desired item(s) without scanning the whole collection:

```js
collection.find({ "cupboards.item": "Sausage" })
```

You can still then "filter" the array content in code to find your matches, or otherwise do something like this using `.aggregate()`:

```js
collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "cupboards.item": "Sausage" }},
    { "$unwind": "$cupboards" },
    { "$match": { "cupboards.item": "Sausage" }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "cupboards": { 
            "$push": {
                "cupboard":"$cupboards.cupboard",
                "item": "$cupboards.item",
                "qty": "$cupboards.qty"
            }
        },
        "totalQty": { "$sum": "$cupboards.qty" }
    }}
])
```

Which produces the same basic result as above, but with less fuss and more speed:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5563e80065536add0d04619c"),
    "cupboards" : [
            {
                    "cupboard" : 2,
                    "item" : "Sausage",
                    "qty" : 3
            }
    ],
    "totalQty" : 3
}
```

So the real point here is to "avoid" using things that are actually "data points" as "key names" in your stored documents. Key names are not indexed and do not make for an efficient search. "Data" can be indexed, and that is the efficient thing to search for.

---

A note on the revised structure for reference. One big difference apart from the general "overhaul" here is the omission of the "total" fields present in the document as originally presented. A big reason for the omission is that even in that original form, the maintenance of such "totals" while adding and updating the other keys is a horrible premise.

There is basically no way of atomically updating all of the values and keeping "totals" in sync without loading/inspecting/re-writing the "whole" document. Singular "fast" updates are just not a possibility in any form.

Whilst it is often a "noble idea" to maintain "totals" in the document as well as the components, the overhead is considerable for more than a single "total". As such, "speedy writes" are often preferred over the additional calculation overhead required on reads in most cases. So it is generally better to follow that model, unless you find that in your particular case that you can live with the additional cost of processing multiple updates to get better performance on read operations.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer @user3561036. I did wonder if the document structure might need some alteration. I guess it takes some time to stop thinking about the real world model (food item is child of cupboard) to a much more flat data model where the location is an attribute of the food item.

Comment: @ChemLynx I think the main point I was making here is that the "logical" approach is that "cupboards" is indeed a "collection" or "array" of possible cupboards with their contents as indeed another collection. Having individual "cupboards" as distinct properties of a master object is not a clean object structure, since the properties themselves vary between objects. The only reason the "arrays" are not nested and "cupboard" is a "property" of the item in the cupboard is that MongoDB  does not intuitively handle nested arrays well for updates. Making the form shown the most efficient.